# mysql join 3 table retain order of data order by used in subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this

```
SELECT a.pmid,a.sendid,a.sendtime,a.recid,a.message,b.unread,r.avator1 ra,s.avator1 sa,s.username sun,r.username run 
FROM pm a 
JOIN 
( 
  SELECT SUM(IF(recid = '347' and hasread=0, 1, 0)) AS undread,
         LEAST(sendid,recid) user1 , 
         GREATEST(sendid,recid) user2 , 
         MAX(pmid) pmid 
  FROM pm 
  WHERE sendid='347' OR recid='347' 
  GROUP BY user1 , user2 
) b 
ON b.pmid = a.pmid 
JOIN
  users s ON s.userid = a.sendid 
JOIN 
  users r ON r.userid=a.recid 
ORDER BY unread DESC, pmid DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

I have performance issue with this query it's taking some 8-10 seconds to complete execution if I alter by removing  `order by unread desc` from the past of the query

query complete execution with in 1 sec but result is wrong,not what i need.

if i move `order by unread desc` inside the subquery example

```
SELECT a.pmid,
       a.sendid,
       a.sendtime,
       a.recid,
       a.message,
       b.unread,
       r.avator1 ra,
       s.avator1 sa,
       s.username sun,
       r.username run
FROM pm a
JOIN
  (SELECT SUM(IF(recid = '347'
                 AND hasread=0, 1, 0)) AS unread,
          LEAST(sendid,recid) user1,
          GREATEST(sendid,recid) user2,
          MAX(pmid) pmid
   FROM pm
   WHERE sendid='347'
     OR recid='347'
   GROUP BY user1,
            user2
   ORDER BY unread DESC,pmid DESC) b ON b.pmid = a.pmid
JOIN users s ON s.userid=a.sendid
JOIN users r ON r.userid=a.recid
LIMIT 0,
      10
```

then it is still not giving result what i need.

if i run the subquery ``

```
SELECT SUM(IF(recid = '347'
              AND hasread=0, 1, 0)) AS unread,
       LEAST(sendid,recid) user1,
       GREATEST(sendid,recid) user2,
       MAX(pmid) pmid
FROM pm
WHERE sendid='347'
  OR recid='347'
GROUP BY user1,
         user2
ORDER BY unread DESC,
         pmid DESC
```

separately then its giving correct data but then if i join user table once with on either recid or sendid then result is correct but when i join user  table twice with both sendid  and recid then the result order is incorrect.

table `pm` structure here

```
CREATE TABLE `pm` (
 `pmid` bigint(40) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sendid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `recid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `subject` mediumtext DEFAULT NULL,
 `message` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `hasread` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
 `sendtime` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `ack` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (`pmid`),
 KEY `sendid_2` (`sendid`,`recid`),
 KEY `recid` (`recid`,`hasread`),
 KEY `recid_2` (`recid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1900982 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

table `users` structure here

```
 CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `userid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
 `username` text CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` text CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `pass` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 `groupid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
 `email` text CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
 `rank` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `validated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 `avator1` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.gif',
 PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33744 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

please help me.

Comment: Could you edit your question's queries (I did the first one) so that they're consistent and legible. You'll get more and better help that way! Also, could you provide the  output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table\G` for all the tables in your query?

Comment: edited my dear.

Comment: And the structure of users?

Comment: edited again...

Comment: Also, some sample data would be great - provided it's not sensitive! Ideally, when asking a question, give the tables (in the form of DDL `CREATE...`), data (in the form of DML - `INSERT...`), your desired output and the logic you are using to obtain that output. Any further information, such as failed attempts &c. is also beneficial. These sites are a great resource - you will get all the more out of them if you can give us everything we could need to help you! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Hmmm... I've looked at this, and it's impossible (or maybe just v. difficult) to see what's wrong (and why) without real data! If you put in the data (DML) and show your resultsets under different circumstances, and compare your original query (which works but is too slow?), with your subsequent ones (which don't return the correct data?).

Answer (score 1):

This kludge allegedly works:  Tack `LIMIT 999999999` onto the subquery.  That forces the optimizer to use the `ORDER BY`.  Normally (in newer versions of MySQL), the Optimizer simply throws away the `ORDER BY` in certain subqueries -- because the SQL Standard says that a subquery delivers an *unordered* set.  [*A reference*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group-by-trick-has-been-optimized-away/).

(Not relevant in *your* case.)  Meanwhile, explicitly add `ORDER BY` in the subquery; don't depend on `GROUP BY` providing an ordering.  That MySQL 'extension' is in flux.  (If the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` are the same, the Optimizer is smart enough to do them together.)

Because of the `OR`, the only practical way to do the subquery is with a full table scan of the 2M rows.

Optimization tip:  Smaller --> faster, especially if the table is too big to be cached.  So...

- Don't use `BIGINT` (8 bytes) when something smaller would suffice.
- Don't use `INT` (4 bytes) for a 'flag'.  `TINYINT` is 1 byte.
- Don't use `TEXT` when `VARCHAR(255 or less)` would suffice.  (There is an extra savings when a tmp table is needed.)